# Is there a simpler way to get a Spotify refresh token other than the auth work flows they have listed?

Tags: access-token, spotify, refresh-token

I’m in the early stages of learning front end development. I have an idea for a project that will interstate the Spotify api but the Spotify access tokens only last for one hour. I wanted to know is there a way I can circumvent this and avoid having to update the token every time I want to use the api. I am aware of the authorization flow but I’m having trouble understanding how to follow it in order to get a refresh token.

I only need to make 2 GET request for getting a track ID then to get the song from that ID

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the official API documentation, an access token lasts one hour but can be refreshed using a refresh token. By using a refresh token you can get a new access token that will be valid for another hour.
Docs: [Spotify guides: token swap and refresh](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/ios/guides/token-swap-and-refresh/)